# Concentration of a random variable around its mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, concentration-of-measure

Consider a random variable $X$.

In general, is it true that the random variable $\log X$ is more tightly concentrated around its expected value than the random variable $X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $n\in\mathbb N$ and $Z\sim N(0,1)\,.$ Then
$$
X:=e^{Z-1/2-n}
$$
has
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X]&=e^{-n}\,,\\[2mm]
\operatorname{Var}[X]&=\mathbb E[e^{2Z-1-2n}]-e^{-2n}\\[2mm]
&=e^{-2n+1}-e^{-2n}\\[2mm]
&=e^{-2n}(e-1)\,,
\end{align}
which becomes arbitrarily small when $n$ is large. On the other hand
$$
\operatorname{Var}[\log X]=\operatorname{Var}[Z]=1\,.
$$

Comment: +1, but I don't understand the computation of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\exp(2Z - 1 - 2n]]$. Why is it valid to plug in $\mathbb{E}[Z] = 0$ there?

Comment: @hunter When you know $\mathbb E[e^{Z-1/2}]=1$ you know them all. To see that this holds plug in the standard normal pdf and merge the exponentials. Then complete the square to see that the integral is still one.